# How to Loop Year and display all data in CGI

Tags: file, cgi

How to Loop Year and display all data under that year in cgi and .dat file

Comment: Please be more specific. How you iterate through (all dates) of a year might be quite language specific. And it's not clear what a .dat file is, if that even matters? Perhaps you want to check for the existence a .dat file corresponding to each date?

Comment: For Example
     Year 2018
         2018 02 06
          Title
           Details
     year 2017
          2017 05 05
          Title
           Details

The year will loop and all data that has that year will display to each year. and the file for ex. is information.dat file that's why i add the .dat extension.

Comment: So you basically have a set of dates you want to sort by year? I still don't understand the issue so I'm guessing here. You might want to first create some kind of sorted index of the dates so you can quickly find the range for each year.

Answer (score 0):

I've already solved my problem here's the link
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e128ebe799cc829bbfab15b8ec007debd5506462

that's a sample for the goal i want.
I do that in php but all i need is the algorithm used in the looping statement. to substitute the data in .DAT file i created a array for data.

Thank you.